# How to attach an external CSS file to the master page correctly?

Tags: php, html, path

I have a web master which all other views will be set in it. Noted that I use Laravel framework. And here is my directory:

```
/myweb
   /resources
      /views
         /master
            /app.blade.php         -- this is web master
         /home.blade.php
         /show.blade.php
   /public
      /css
         /app.css
```

Now I attach `app.css` in the `app.blade.php` file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
```

Well, something odd happens here ^ .. `app.css` will be found when I open `home.blade.php`, but it will be not found when I open `show.blade.php`.

**Note:** If I attach `app.css` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.css">
```

then it will work for `show.blade.php`, but it doesn't work for `home.blade.php`.

Why? And how can I fix it? I mean how can I write a path which works for both pages?

Comment: Try using like this `<link href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I have posted as answer! It was pleasure to help you out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using like this:

```
<link href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is reference: https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravels-url-to-vs-url-asset-fd427ed6f7ef#.zcmf83z03